How can I define a key handler that uses state?
I'm using function components because I understand that's the modern way. I want to define a key handler which accesses component state. The intuitive and elegant methods don't work.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

I've tried 3 methods:
Method 1
export default function CounterApp() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => document.addEventListener(
    'keydown', 
    (e) => {
      console.log("Got keystroke", e.key, counter);
      if (e.key === "1") {
        setCounter(counter + 1);
      }
    }
  ), []);

  console.log("render");
  return  <div>The counter is: {counter}</div>
}

Method 2:
export default function CounterApp() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(
    () => document.addEventListener('keydown', keyhandler),
    []
  );

  function keyhandler(e) {
    console.log("Got keystroke", e.key, counter);
    if (e.key === "1") {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
  }

  console.log("render");
  return  <div>The counter is: {counter}</div>
}

Method 3:
export default function CounterApp() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyhandler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyhandler);
  }, [counter]);

  function keyhandler(e) {
    console.log("Got keystroke", e.key, counter);
    if (e.key === "1") {
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }
  }

  console.log("render");
  return  <div>The counter is: {counter}</div>
}

Method 3 actually works, but it seems like a lot of typing, probably inefficient (frequent calls of useEffect), and error-prone, so I'm wondering why the more straightforward approaches don't work. I'd prefer to add the event listener just once in the component's lifetime, adding a function that never changes (so no need to add it as a useEffect dependency), although the function references a state variable which does change. Does React really need to reparse a function definition anytime there's a change to its state-variable inputs? Is the 3rd approach correct and optimal? What is wrong with the first two methods?

See the React docs for Updating state based on the previous state — and useEffect which documents the purpose of a cleanup function

Method 3 is close (it works but it's not ideal, like you said), but you shouldn't define keyhandler outside the effect, you should define it inside.
Your main problem (in method 2 as well, which almost worked, but still not ideal because of the missing return function in useEffect) was that you were missing the state updater as a function and instead you were either capturing the value of counter when your event listener was attached (it's always 0 on first render and every time a key is pressed counter will still be 0).
This:
setCounter(c => c+1)

instead of:
setCounter(counter+1)

If you update the state using a function, you only need to apply the effect on mount instead of when counter changes:
export default function CounterApp() {
    const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyhandler = (e) => {
          if(e.key === "1") setCounter(c => c+1)
        }
    
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyhandler);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyhandler);
    },[]);

    console.log("render");
    return  <div>The counter is: {counter} </div>
}

Example of a reusable useKeyPress hoook:
const useKeyPress = (key, fn) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (e) => {
      if (e.key === key) fn();
    };
    document.addEventListener('keypress', listener);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keypress', listener);
  }, [key, fn]);
};

Used like so:
const [count,setCount] = useState(0)
useKeyPress('1',() => setCount(c => c+1);


Thanks Adam!  It all seems rather clunky and unfriendly to React beginners but I guess this is how it needs to be done.

@TimCooper - feels clunky, but this stuff can be hidden away in a custom hook useKeyPress - kind of like this one to present a more comfortable API (that does the exact same thing) instead of putting all of the useEffect in a single component. React is super composable in this manner.

@TimCooper - I actually updated my answer to include what a userland useKeyPress hook would look like - it's pretty simple, and then you could use it everywhere you needed to.
